# DropdownButton selection in Flutter using Provider state management

Tags: flutter, dropdown, provider

Following this sample code [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) I was able to display dropdown and change its selection using provider with the following code. But as soon as I change the data types from String to my custom created CityModel I am getting exception error:

[image]

my_screen.dart

```
class MyScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).fetchApiList("City"),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          Widget children;

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            children = DropdownButton<CityModel>(
              value: Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).selectedCity,
              icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
              elevation: 16,
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
              underline: Container(
                height: 2,
                color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
              ),
              onChanged: (CityModel? newValue) {
                Provider.of<MyProvider>(context, listen: false).setSelectedCity(newValue!);
              },
              items: Provider.of<MyProvider>(context).listOfRecords.map<DropdownMenuItem<CityModel>>((CityModel value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<CityModel>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(value.cityName),
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            children = const Text("data");
          } else {
            children = const Text("data");
          }

          return Center(
            child: children,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

my_provider.dart

```
class MyProvider extends ChangeNotifier {

  var listOfRecords = <CityModel>[];
  CityModel selectedCity = CityModel(cityName: "Select City");

  Future<List<CityModel>> fetchApiList(String type) async {
    try {
      String endPoint = ApiLinks.commonList;

      switch (type) {
        case "City":
          endPoint = endPoint + ApiLinks.cityList;
          break;
        default:
      }

      var apiResponse = await ApiHelper.apiGetRequest(endPoint);
      var jsonResponse = jsonDecode(apiResponse);

      var apiList = (jsonResponse["data"] as List).map((m) {
        return CityModel.fromMap(m);
      }).toList();

      listOfRecords.clear();
      listOfRecords.add(CityModel(cityName: "Select City"));
      listOfRecords.addAll(apiList);

      return apiList;
    } catch (e) {}
  }

  void setSelectedCity(CityModel selection) {
    selectedCity.cityName = selection.cityName;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Really stuck plz guide me where I am going wring.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `DropdownMenuItem` should be unique.

Comment: It is unique. Would you plz elaborate more what's wrong here.

Comment: take a loot at error message: it points that value are not unique.